# Trying to log in using Cypress.io, but getting CORS error 'Mismatched Origin'

Tags: javascript, node.js, user-interface, testing, cypress

I'm trying to login to my app using cypress.io, but am getting the error "Mismatched Origin".

According to the documentation, we can bypass CORS by setting `chromeWebSecurity:false` inside our `cypress.json`, but I'm still getting CORS errors.

https://docs.cypress.io/guides/references/error-messages.html#Page-Load-Errors

Cypress documentation discourages logging in using the UI, so I'm using the `cy.request()` method as follows:

Here is my `cypress.json` file:

```
{
    "chromeWebSecurity": false,
    "baseUrl": "http://localhost:1234"
}
```

Here is my `test.js` file:

```
      method: 'POST',
      url: 'http://localhost:3000/login',
      body: { 
        username: 'user',
        password: 'password', 
        credentails: 'include'
      }
    })
```

And the error from Cypress:

```
Status: 400 - Bad Request
Headers: {
  "server": "BaseHTTP/0.6 Python/3.7.9",
  "date": "Thu, 24 Dec 2020 00:49:06 GMT",
  "content-length": "30",
  "content-type": "application/json"
}
Body: {
  "error": "Mismatched origin."
}
```

I'm wondering if anyone has had luck making a request to a service on a different port to login to in Cypress? Thanks in advance!

Comment: `headers: {'Allow-Control-Allow-Origin': "*"}` will not be effective nested inside `body`.

Comment: Thanks, I took that out and am still getting the same error.

Comment: You removed the CORS header, but instead should have placed it outside the body.